# Find out all the punctuations in a sentence that has been put into a list

Tags: python, list, punctuation

I have this variable:

```
Words = ["Hi",".","how","are","you","?","I","feel","like","I","could",",","do","better"]
```

From this I want a variable that finds all the punctuations and puts it into a list as well. Like this:

```
Punctuations = [".","?",","]
```

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it, did you make any attempt?

Comment: i used the method string.punctuation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) to identify punctuation marks:

```
from string import punctuation
punctuations = [w for w in words if w in punctuation]
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `re.findall` function:

```
import re

Words = ["Hi",".","how","are","you","?","I","feel","like","I","could",",","do","better"]
Punctuations = re.findall("[^\w\s]+", ''.join(Words))

print(Punctuations)  # ['.', '?', ',']
```